# Validar número de telefone com nono dígito opcional

Tags: php, regex

Como validar número de telefone com o nono dígito opcional? nos seguintes formatos:

DDD + 8 dígitos = (21) 9876-5432

DDD + 9 dígitos = (21) 98765-4321

Comment: Sendo regex dá para simplificar bem mais e outra não é só o ddd que tem 9 digitos, quase todos estados do Angola e não só já adotaram, acho que faltam poucos

Answer (score 10):

Desde 2013 os celulares com DDD 21 passaram a ter o nono digito, não vejo porque ser opcional, se você estiver dizendo que a entrada pode ser telefone fixo tanto quanto celular eu recomendo que não faça isto, vai dar muita dor de cabeça

Mas se é o que deseja você pode fazer assim:

```
^\(\d{2}\) 9?[6789]\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Usando o `9?` dentro da regex o numero 9 fica opcional, mas ainda sim identifica se é um celular, se começa com 99, 98, 97 e 96 ou 9, 8, 7 e 6, pois dentro da regex tem isto `[6789]`

Ficando assim:

```
<?php
$celular = '(21) 98765-4321';

if (preg_match('#^\(\d{2}\) 9?[6789]\d{3}-\d{4}$#', $celular) > 0) {
     echo 'Validou';
} else {
     echo 'Não validou';
}
```

- Exemplo online: http://ideone.com/jlLdS1
- Exemplo Regex: https://regex101.com/r/L5xzol/2

### Como validar celulares com e sem o nono digito

Note que celulares começam com 96, 97, 98 e 99 (ou 6, 7, 8 e 9 se não tiver o nono digito) como citei antes e conforme a [Anatel](http://www.anatel.gov.br/Portal/exibirPortalPaginaEspecial.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=9594e1d11fbc996d52bda44e608bb744&codItemCanal=1794&pastaSelecionada=2984) serão estes os DDDs que terão o nono digito:

A [Resolução nº 553/2010](http://www.anatel.gov.br/legislacao/resolucoes/2010/16-resolucao-553) da Anatel determinou a implementação do nono dígito em todo o Brasil.

- O DDD 11 (cidade de São Paulo e região metropolitana) ganhou o nono dígito em 29 de julho de 2012.
- Em 25 de agosto de 2013, foi a vez dos DDD 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 e 19 (restante do estado de São Paulo).
- Em 27 de outubro de 2013, foram alterados os números dos DDD 21, 22 e 24 (estado do Rio de Janeiro), e 27 e 28 (estado do Espírito Santo).
- Em 02 de novembro de 2014, serão alterados os números dos DDD 91, 93 e 94 (estado do Pará), 92 e 97 (estado do Amazonas), 95 (estado de Roraima), 96 (estado do Amapá), 98 e 99 (estado do Maranhão).
- Até 31 de dezembro de 2015, serão alterados os números dos DDD 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37 e 38 (estado de Minas Gerais), 71, 73, 74, 75 e 77 (estado da Bahia), 79 (estado do Sergipe), 81 e 87 (estado do Pernambuco), 82 (estado de Alagoas), 83 (estado da Paraíba), 84 (estado do Rio Grande do Norte), 85 e 88 (estado do Ceará), e 86 e 89 (estado do Piauí).
- Até 31 de dezembro de 2016, serão alterados os números dos DDD 41, 42, 43, 44, 45 e 46 (estado do Paraná), 47, 48 e 49 (estado de Santa Catarina), 51, 53, 54 e 55 (estado do Rio Grande do Sul), 61 (Distrito Federal), 62 e 64 (estado do Goiás), 63 (estado do Tocantins), 65 e 66 (estado do Mato Grosso), 67 (estado do Mato Grosso do Sul), 68 (estado do Acre) e 69 (estado de Rondônia).

Ou seja para a validação ser mais precisa precisamos de um RegEx mais "enxuto", no caso eu sugiro algo como:

```
^(\((11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|21|22|24|27|28|91|92|93|94|95|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|31|32|33|34|35|37|38|71|73|74|75|77|79|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|49|51|53|54|55)\) 9|\((?!11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|21|22|24|27|28|91|92|93|94|95|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|31|32|33|34|35|37|38|71|73|74|75|77|79|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|49|51|53|54|55)\d{2}\) )[6789]\d{3}\-\d{4}$
```

Ficou um pouco longa, simplificado para explicar como funciona, seria algo assim:

```
^(\((11|21)\) 9|\((?!11|21)\d{2}\) )[6789]\d{3}\-\d{4}$
     ^        ^    ^                 ^     ^
     1        2    3                 4     5
```

1. Verifica se o começa com os DDDs da lista do nono digito
2. Verifica se o numero começa com nono digito se acaso for um dos DDDs da lista
3. Verifica se o numero não começa com os DDDs da lista e também não deve ter o nono digito
4. Verifica se o numero do telefone começa com 6, 7, 8, 9, 96, 97, 98 ou 99
5. Verifica se se o resto que vem depois do prefixo é numero

Neste segundo exemplo só aceita os DDDs 11 e 21 para telefone com o nono digito e se não tiver o nono digito ele só aceita os que **não tem** o DDD 21 e 11.

Uma função para checagem seria algo como:

```
<?php
function validarCelular($celular)
{
    static $regex;

    if ($regex === null) {
        //Coloquei em um array para identificar melhor
        $ddds = implode('|', array(
            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
            21, 22, 24, 27, 28,
            91, 92, 93, 94, 95,
            81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,
            31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38,
            71, 73, 74, 75, 77, 79,
            61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
            49, 51, 53, 54, 55
        ));

        //Gera a regex
        $regex = '#^(\((' . $ddds . ')\) 9|\((?!' . $ddds . ')\d{2}\) )[6789]\d{3}-\d{4}$#';
    }

    return preg_match($regex, $celular) > 0;
}

$celular = '(21) 98765-4321';

if (validarCelular($celular)) {
     echo 'Validou';
} else {
     echo 'Não validou';
}
```

- Exemplo PHP: http://ideone.com/jW2M7L
- Exemplo Regex: https://regex101.com/r/BgVq0G/2 fiz simplificado e com vários números para entender o "match" dentro do campo, note que ele não pega os inválidos

Comment: Que que é isso @GuilhermeNascimento? `11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|21|22|24|27|28|91|92|93|94|95|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|31|32|33|34|35|37|38|71|73|74|75|77|79|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|49|51|53|54|55`, usa assim  `([1356789][1345])|([123689]2)|([167][79])|([16][68])|([23][78])|(8[67])|(2[14])|49`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu pensei nisto, o problema é a questão anatel adicionar algo novo, então isolei em um array. Mas ainda sim é uma otima dica :)

Comment: Ah entendi boa ideia :D

Comment: Fiz alguns testes sua regex não funcionou

Comment: Caro @BrunoR não funcionou como? Concorda que não funcionou é bastante ambiguo? Deu algum erro? Testou com PHP? Qual valor passou? Tem espaços no fim e começo da string passada no valor? DÊ detalhes, se não é impossivel ajudar, e realmente quero ajudar-lo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento calma jovem, eu testei igual ta no exemplo, de 2 formas, que seria apenas para celulares. 1 = (82) 6 9926-5288 & 2 = (88) 8 8888-8888.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou sem tempo agora, estou implementando uma API, enfim será o espaço ? que deu problema ? vou deixa essa página aberto e qndo tiver tempo vou fazer um post com uma uma função de validação de telefone mais transante que a sua ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você está certo meu caro,  não é a função que eu precisava, você só atendeu a necessidade do cara que fez a pergunta, enfim erro meu e  por esse erro da +1 na sua resposta.

Comment: caro @BrunoR agora que olhei com mais calma, seus telefones não tem nada haver com a ANATEL, logo você tentou usar algo para um proposito especifico, **digito nove**, não tem como algo especifico funcionar em todos lugares, regex é incrivel, mas não é mágica, formule uma pergunta que irei sugerir um exemplo de resposta especifico **para sua necessidade** ;)

Answer (score 6):

Amigo, a algum tempo atrás utilizei o seguinte regex para fazer sua validação:

```
(\(?\d{2}\)?) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}
```

Adicionei o mesmo à comunidade do regexr: http://regexr.com/3emuj

Espero ter ajudado.

P.S: Você pode inserir esse regex no  atributo pattern do input referente ao telefone para fazer uma validação client-side.

**Edit:**

Exemplo de utilização de regex com a função `preg_match()`:

```
<?php
$telefone = '(21) 98765-4321';
if (preg_match('/(\(?\d{2}\)?) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}/', $telefone)) {
    echo "O telefone passou na validação";
} else {
    echo "O telefone não passou na validação";
}
?>
```

Você pode encontrar mais exemplos ná página referente a função preg_match() na documentação oficial do PHP:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Desculpe, não tenho muita experiência com regex, joguei num preg_match e me retornou: 

**preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' in**

Comment: Opa amigo: tenta utilizando /[EXPRESSÃO]/g, vou adicionar uma linha na resposta para melhor ilustrar.

Comment: Deu isso agora: **preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'** usei o exemplo que você atualizou a resposta.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3,  cara corrigi o código da resposta. Desta vez eu testei localmente. Desculpa pelo /g, eu troquei as bolas com o string.replace() do JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigado, testei, porém ele está aceitando mais números que o máximo.

Comment: Como assim mais números que o maximo? @NGTHM4R3

Comment: Renoir está faltando o `^...$`, por isto está aceitando "mais numeros que o maximo", como disse o @NGTHM4R3, isto deve resolver `preg_match('/^(\(?\d{2}\)?) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/', $telefone)`

Comment: Guilherme, tentei usar o preg_match_all para pegar todos os números de um texto com este regex e não retornou nada, por que?

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Renoir Dos Reis está com uns errinhos, fiz umas pequenas alterações

```
^((\(\d{2}\))|\d{2}) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}$
```

o **^** no início significa que a expressão precisa obrigatoriamente começar por ali e o **$** significa que precisa obrigatoriamente terminar ali. Da forma como estava aceitaria qualquer string que contivesse um telefone no meio, *sfsjkahfsjka2199999999vsjkv* passaria como correta.

Inclui o **|\d{2}** e removi o **?** dos parenteses. O **|** significa **ou** então dessa forma aceita tanto *(21)9999-9999* quanto *21 9999-9999*, mas não aceita *(219999-9999* nem *21)9999-9999*. Da forma como estava antes os parenteses eram individualmente opcionais, agora se tem um dos parenteses obrigatoriamente precisa ter o outro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte regra:

```
$exp_regular = '^(\(11\) [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$';
$ret = preg_match($exp_regular, $phone);

preg_match($exp_regular, '(11) 92222-2222');
preg_match($exp_regular, '(43) 8222-2222');
```

Comment: O nono dígito já é nacional desde o começo do mês, todos os estados já usam: http://www.tim.com.br/mg/nonodigito

Comment: Não sabia, inclusive sou do Paraná e aqui não se tem falado muito sobre isso...vou corrigir...

Comment: Me retornou: **preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in**, eu botei o ^ no final, funcionou só para 9 dígitos.

Comment: Sendo regex dá para simplificar bem mais e outra não é só o ddd que tem 9 digitos, quase todos estados do Brasil já adotaram, acho que faltam poucos