# quero fazer uma validação de telefone mais como faço para validar o traço também caso o usuário coloque?

Tags: php, regex

isto é o que tenho até agora:

```
public static function ValidaFone($RegeEx)
{
 $RegeEx = preg_match('/^[0-9]{9,11,13}$/',$RegeEx);

      ........code.....
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validar número de telefone com nono dígito opcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166484/5878)

Comment: Qual é o formato esperado?

Comment: primeira vez que uso regex como faço para dizer que o nono digito no caso o traço pode ser opcional ?

Comment: O traço é algo 'opcional' e 'pessoal', depois do acréscimo de mais um nove, já vi gente escrevendo o tel com dois traços:  `9-9999-9999`. Remova o traço e grave apenas os números.

Comment: formato esperado é que o usuário digite o telefone eu valide se ele digito código de área , ou só telefone ou com o código do pais mais preciso justamente validar no regex tambem exatamente como ele disse deixando o traço opcional caso ele digite ou não mais como faço isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os traços dos telefones só podem estar presentes em posições específicas, certo?

```
/^([0-9]{5}(-| )?[0-9]{4})$/
```

Essa regex diz o seguinte:

- cinco números entre zero e nove;
- um espaço ou hífen, opcional;
- quatro números entre zero e nove.

Você pode refinar a expressão para não permitir, por exemplo, números de telefone iniciados por zero, ou para incluir mais trechos como código de área.

Para entender qualquer expressão regular em JS, recomendo o site http://regex101.com/. Você pode colocar uma expressão lá e o site explica os trechos.

Comment: obrigado @Renan pensando assim tem como vc me deu uma ideia dessa forma não valido caso usuário digite tambem o código do pais que seriam mais dois caracter mais me deu uma boa ideia para isso valeu